# Chrome pages turns blank after loading

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android

I have been having this happen to me for a long time now but recently it seems like it has gotten worse.

What happens is that

A page loads, and you can see the webpage and almost all content while its loading. You can scroll and use as normal, but once the page fully loads it turns to a fully blank page.

Sometimes it happens really fast on light pages, other times on heavy pages you are able to see the page then when it does load it goes blank.

Even with a refresh the same thing happens.

The way to fix it is to clear the app from recent apps. Open back up chrome then it loads fine.

Its not every page its not all the time but its at least everyday. Its happened with 1 tab open to 10 tabs open. On all kinds of different sites and pages.

Any ideas on why this is? Anyone else experiencing the same thing?

Comment: Yes, I've seen the same behavior. If I open a new tab and go to a different site it usually works. Otherwise, I just fire up Opera instead.

Comment: I've been getting the same problem on moto g. Had to uninstall updates (back to version 34) in the end which fixed the problem. Waiting for version 37 before I try again.

Comment: I usually get around it by copying and pasting the URL into a new tab.

Answer (score 3):

A bug in the latest version of Chrome can cause this in certain circumstances (low memory being one). Details here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=342190
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=399521

Seems like a fix should be making its way into the beta soon.

Comment: I wouldn't say latest version because I have updated my chrome many times and the problem has been around for a long time now just in the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds similar to a bug with 16-bit transparency. If your phone has this setting, turn it off, then try again, but your bug does seem a little different, so no promises.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I usually just press the home button to go back to my home screen of my phone, then I hold the home button and clear apps running in the background. Then I open chrome again and the screen is displayed properly.

Only solution I have until the bug gets fixed in beta.